# How to highlight list first item when list get focus? (mfc)

Tags: mfc

I am trying to provide keyboard support.
Whenever Clist get focus it should highlight the first row.

i used following APIs provided by mfc.
List.setselectionmark(0)
List.SetItemState(nItem, 0, LVIS_SELECTED);

but it is not highlighting the first item.
if i press up/down key then it is highlighting.

How to highlight  first item when list get focus?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [SetItemState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t97k8h9.aspx) function, but the second parameter needs to specify which item state you are modifying, see `stateMask` in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774760.aspx).

So your code should look like

```
SetItemState(nItem, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
```